# Namespace with duplicate resource name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I'm new to rails, and trying to develop a system that will have several different types of user. I'm trying to use namespaces to separate these areas, but I want the models to be shared. I've created a user object, and I want to be able to edit it from the admin namespace.  I've scaffolded an Admin::UserController, and defined the routes as:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
end

root :to => "home#index"
```

When I go to `admin/users` it shows fine, but clicking 'Create User' gave me an NoMethodError, saying it couldn't find the path `users_path`. After searching I realised I needed to update my routes.rb to:

```
resources :users

namespace :admin do
    resources :users
end

root :to => "home#index"
```

Now I can get to the `admin/users/new` form, but when I post it tries to return to `/users`. My two questions are: 1. how can I make this work? and 2. am I even approaching this correctly trying to use namespaces in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have routes generated for both `/admin/users` and `/users`. If you want to use `Admin::UsersController` use `admin_users_path` and if you wish to use `UsersController` use `users_path` in your form.

I would also like to suggest you to use `rake routes` command if you ever wonder what are the names of the generated routes.